# How to I change GNOME 3.8 top bar font?

Tags: fonts

It can not be changed through GNOME Tweak Tool, so anyone know the answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a quick and dirty solution, simply edit

```
/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css
```

Of course this will likely get overwritten the next time you update your gnome-shell package.

The cleaner (but a bit more complex) way is to create you own (mini-)theme:

http://rlog.rgtti.com/2012/01/29/how-to-modify-a-gnome-shell-theme/

Comment: This no longer works (3.18). I realise the OP specified gnome 3.8, but comment is just so others like me don't think "oh, I wonder if it will work today..." :-)